# Mysql, remove duplicates and SUM in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a clients table that contains repeated data, for example: a client with phone 1234 is in the same store multiple times.

I tried the following code to get all duplicate clients with the same phone in the same store:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id
        SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
FROM
    clients
GROUP BY phone , store_id
HAVING COUNT(phone) > 1
```

Tables:

```
CLIENTS
id    phone   store_id
------------------------
1     1234       3
2     1234       3
3     4321       4
4     4321       4
5     4321       4

USER_POINTS
id   client_id     points
------------------------
1       1            10
2       2            5
3       3            2
4       4            9
5       5            1
```

How can I delete duplicate clients from the client table while SUM their points to a single points table row and update the rest with `-1`?
I tried the following, but didn't get the desired result.

```
UPDATE user_points AS up,
    (SELECT 
        client_id,
            MIN(id) AS min_id,
            SUM(points) AS sum_points
    FROM
        user_points
    WHERE
        client_id IN (SELECT id FROM clients GROUP BY phone, store_id HAVING COUNT(phone) > 1)) AS p 
SET 
    up.points = CASE
        WHEN up.id = p.min_id THEN p.sum_points
        ELSE -1
    END;
```

I wanted something like:

```
USER_POINTS
id   client_id     points
------------------------
1       1            15
2       2            -1
3       3            12
4       4            -1
5       5            -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` from `user_points` to your derived table of sums of client points and minimum client id values, and then set the value of `points` when the `min_id` value is `NOT NULL`:

```
UPDATE user_points u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
               MIN(c.id) AS min_id,
               SUM(points) AS sum_points
           FROM
               clients c
           JOIN 
               user_points u ON u.client_id = c.id
           GROUP BY phone, store_id) c ON u.client_id = c.min_id
SET u.points = CASE WHEN c.min_id IS NOT NULL THEN c.sum_points ELSE -1 END
```

Output:

```
id  client_id   points
1   1           15
2   2           -1
3   3           12
4   4           -1
5   5           -1
```

Demo (slightly expanded to include a different store for phone `1234`) on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=de918ac25540d9c900ffe0cc0d3d2496).